# Código python para exportar tabela postgres com imagens

Tags: python, postgresql

Preciso gravar em um arquivo os registros de uma tabela no postgres, sendo que um dos campos contém imagens.
Qual comando para exportar, e qual formato do arquivo?

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database=db,
                    host="localhost",
                    user=user,
                    password=pwd,
                    port=porta)
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = ("COPY (SELECT description, picture FROM categories) TO STDOUT (FORMAT BINARY)")
path = ".\data\postgres"
```

Comment: Ao invés de criar algo em python não seria mais apropriado utilizar as ferramentas de backup [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) e [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) ambos usando a opção `--table`?

Comment: Parece ser a solução, mas não teria como executar esses utilitários a partir do python?

Comment: Para resolver essa tarefa, preciso entregar código, não necessariamente python. Mas tem que ser código, em qualquer linguagem. Além disso, o postgreSql com a tabela está em uma imagem docker.

Comment: O módulo python [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) permite gerar novos processos. Veja em especial a função [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Comment: Usei a solução do furins aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732900/postgresql-database-backup-using-python